# MVVMCross : Creating an MvxFragment crashing the application

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have integerated MVVMCross in my applications and activities are gtting binded with the Viewmodels without any error. However, when i create the following MvxFragment file, the project throws following exceptions (and removing the file again shows login activity as expected, without any error)

The MvxFragment class

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragments;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Presenters.Attributes;


namespace App.Driod.UI.Fragments
{
    public class SettingsView : MvxFragment<SettingsViewModel>
    {

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            var ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
            return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_simple, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Error After adding the SettingsView class

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'Could not find view for Core.ViewModels.LoginViewModel'
```

I am searching for a solution for this. Thanks

Comment: Is your namespace in the LoginView also `App.Driod.UI.Fragments` instead of Droid?

Comment: No, Its in  - App.Driod.UI.Activities.